# Why is the `innerHTML` property owned by the JavaScript `Element` class rather than `HTMLElement`?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, prototype

I am studying the document object model implemented in JavaScript, and I understand (this according to MDN) that the `Element` class/prototype is meant to represent an element of an arbitrary document, e.g. HTML, XML, or even SVG documents. In contrast, the `HTMLElement` sub-class is meant to represent elements of specifically HTML documents. However, this does not seem to be totally borne out by the actual ownership of properties between the two classes.

In particular, why is the property `innerHTML`, which seems to be specific to HTML documents, owned by the `Element` prototype?

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Element.prototype).includes('innerHTML')
>>> true
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(HTMLElement.prototype).includes('innerHTML')
>>> false
```

Similarly, I observe that the `body` and `head` properties are owned by `Document.prototype`, rather than `HTMLDocument.prototype`. This seems peculiar as I wouldn't expect all types of documents to have a head and body.

Is this just JS compatibility/legacy weirdness? (If so, I wonder if there is a story of how it came about) Or is there some logic to this property-ownership structure that I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `innerHTML`, that was not before HTML5 that it made it to the specs, it was an IE invention that got adopted by others vendors later on, before the specs caught on.
There was active discussions about renaming it or even limiting it to the `HTMLElement` interface. (e.g see the note in this [HTML5 draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#dynamic2), or [this comment](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=26804#c3) on a related DOM issue.)
But keeping it for MathML or even SVG elements still made sense, so they kept it as it was designed by the vendors.

---

For the Document case... that's an even bigger mess.
It seems that since DOM 1 the `body` property wasn't on [`Document`](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#i-Document) but on [`HTMLDocument`](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#attribute-body) only and `head` wasn't there at all.
In DOM 3 the `HTMLDocument` interface was no more part of the DOM specs and still isn't in [DOM LS](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/). It is now [specced by HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#htmldocument), but only so that is it an alias to the `Document` interface.
It's also in the [HTML specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#document) that `body` and `head` are defined as an extension to the `Document` interface.

This is following an attempt to merge all `[XXX]Document` interfaces into `Document`, while some decided to never do that, some to undo and ... well, as I said it's a mess. I guess the most up to date discussion is [here](https://github.com/whatwg/dom/issues/221). For some history you can look at [this bug](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=22960) and [this one](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=19431) and everything linked there.

In the facts, it seems every modern browsers now indeed kept `HTMLDocument` as an alias to `Document`, with no added properties:

```js
const own_props = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors( HTMLDocument.prototype );
console.log( Object.keys( own_props ) ); // [ "constructor" ] => doesn't add anything to Document
```

<sub>Ps: (note that the DOM is *usually* not implemented in javascript).</sub>

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the great answer. I enjoyed reading through the linked discussions, so interesting how these decisions are made. And what a mess indeed. For the future, I must learn how to dig through docs/discussions as you have here.